# Visual Studio 'null' is not defined

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to learn Visual Studio with VB and started by using the Microsoft training by creating a Picture Viewer form.

Everything was going fine and I figured out how to use VB code which is slightly different than the examples in C#.  I have most of the training done and can bring in a pictures from the app, but I am having trouble with the closeButton based on the code provided.  I am at a loss after searching for many hours.  The following is the code from the Open Picture and Close Code.  As I was inputting the code from the interface there was no null so I typed it in and that didn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles showButton.Click
        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        End If
        PictureBox1.Load(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles clearButton.Click
    PictureBox1.Image = null
End Sub
```

Comment: `PictureBox1.Load(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)` goes inside the If/End If block. The *clear* Button should have `PictureBox1.Image.Dispose()` and `pictureBox1.Image = nothing` to clear it.

Answer (score 1):

Think if you change null to Nothing, you should be all good

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles clearButton.Click
    PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: This is correct, but do note that there is a subtle difference between C# `null` and VB `Nothing`.  C# `null` specifically refers to a null value for a reference type.  VB `Nothing` refers to "default value for type" (which is `null` for a reference type) and is more nearly equivalent to C# `default`.  Also see Anthony Green's "exhausting" list of differences: https://anthonydgreen.net/2019/02/12/exhausting-list-of-differences-between-vb-net-c/

Comment: Thank you that worked fine.  Probably a dumb question but I'm new and learning.

Answer (score 0):

Change the keyword `null` to `nothing` please .

For non-nullable value types, Nothing in Visual Basic differs from null in C#. In Visual Basic, if you set a variable of a non-nullable value type to Nothing, the variable is set to the default value for its declared type. If a variable is of a value type, the behavior of Nothing depends on whether the variable is of a nullable data type. If a variable is of a reference type, assigning Nothing to the variable sets it to a null reference of the variable's type.
See [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/nothing) for more details and demo.